# MySQL Error Code 1166. Incorrect column name

Tags: mysql, sql

When I try to run a routine I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1166. Incorrect column name 'School.`School Name` = case
>   when School.`Web School Name` is null then School.`School Name` 
>   els'

I have double checked the column name and there is in fact a `School.School Name`.  There are no leading or trailing spaces.  Here is the beginning of the routine that the error is referring to:

```
CREATE temporary TABLE tt_Step1
SELECT DISTINCT State.Code, State.Name, 
School.`School Name` = case 
    when School.`Web School Name` is null then School.`School Name`
    else School.`Web School Name`
    end,
School.`School ID` 
-- Into tt_Step1
FROM State LEFT JOIN School ON State.Code = School.State 
Where (School.`School ID` <> ...
```

I recently converted this code from MSSQL to MySQL so there may be something I missed but I cannot find any errors.  The original MSSQL query runs fine in SQL Server Management Studio but the converted version of it in MySQL does not.

Comment: Column name with space can't happen in MySQL : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: @DavidBélanger: That is absolutely not true.  The only thing that linked doc says is `cannot **end** with space characters`.

Comment: Why down vote this? This is a perfectly fine SO question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
CREATE temporary TABLE tt_Step1
SELECT DISTINCT State.Code, State.Name, 
coalesce(School.`Web School Name`, School.`School Name`),
School.`School ID` 
-- Into tt_Step1
FROM State LEFT JOIN School ON State.Code = School.State 
Where (School.`School ID` <> ...
```

Comment: I used "coalesce(School.`Web School Name`, School.`School Name`) as `School Name`".  This mostly works but sometimes the School Name is returning as a 0 or a 1 for some entries.

Comment: All coalesce does is check the first argument for null, if it's null, use the second argument instead.  If you're getting back "0" and "1" from the coalesce, it's because there's data in your School table with  "0" and "1" in those columns.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what is going on.  I checked the table manually and with a query and did not find any values of 0 or 1.  Anyways, I used the old case statement and aliased it correctly and both results returned the same thing so I will accept this answer.  I am having other problems apparently. Thank you very much for the assistance.

Answer (score 13):

In my case, it was caused by an unseen extra space after the column name. I wrote `promotion-ids` instead of `promotion-id`.

Comment: `promotion-ids` vs `promotion-id`  does not look like an extra space at the end to me

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of issues.

1. You cannot alias a column with a multi-part name like `School.School Name`.
2. Aliasing in MySql is done with `blah as ColumnName`, not `ColumnName = blah`.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem.  My problem was resolved by adding a column name to the case statement.

Example:

```
Case

  when val <.5 then "low"

  when val >1 then "high"

end as valTest
```

without `as valTest` I would get the 1166 error.